# VPN через корпоративный прокси

Tags: сеть, vpn, openvpn, l2tp

Суть: есть локальная сеть `172.26.10.0/24`, выход в интернет из нее через прокси `172.26.15.252` по паре *логин-пароль*. 
Прокси режет **ICMP**, но не режет **TCP 80/443/21/22**. Есть также удаленная локальная сеть `192.168.1.0/24`, хост `192.168.1.1` имеет прямой выход в интернет + включена служба *CloudDNS (Mikrotik)*, т.о. внешний ip динамический, поднят NAT.

Планирую поднять в сети `192.168.1.0/24` OpenVPN-сервер, а в сети `172.26.10.0/24` настроить клиента. 
Вопрос, будет ли установлено соединение между клиентом и сервером по VPN, если прокси режет ICMP?

Comment: Добавлю что L2TP/IPSec из сети А до сети B без использования прокси, т.е. по схеме client A-->router1-->pppoe-->internet<--pppoe<--router2<--client B работает отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ "Да". Соединение будет. 
Я не специалист в этой области,но провёл тестирование. Выяснилось, что ICMP никак не участвует. Корп.прокси режет все, кроме 80/443. Первоначально задачу решил пробросом портов на роутере. Работает. Не понравилось.

Потом сделал SSH-туннелирование, потратил день.Немного тормозно, зато в обе стороны и шифруется.

Сегодня уже разобрался в настройках OpenVPN (спасибо bozza). Оказалось всё банально и просто. Поскольку прокси разрешает только 80/443, openvpn сервер настроил на 443 порт. В конфигурации клиента OpenVPN прописал прокси-сервер/логин-пасс. После этого - всё заработало.

Для себя выяснил несколько моментов. Из под Win/*nix проблем с софтом и настройкой не возникает, полдня посидеть-решается. А вот под Android - сложно заставить идти SSH Tunnel через ProxyDroid. Еще сложнее потом перенастроить что-то на локальный прокси.

p.s. И единственный сакс остался у меня с OpenVPN под андройд, который не дружит с TAP, только с TUN. А под Win получилось работать только с TAP.